# Android Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar can not be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I am facing an annoying error.

```
Can not resolve Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

See the screenshot below
[image]

Please if anyone could help.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you are on the latest `appcompat-v7` (25.0.1, IIRC).

Comment: show your gradle and manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a theme and then apply in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new android project and compare the style.xml with your projects style.xml file and you will get the missing parts and out of sync items there by the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thought its long time, I recently faced same issue. Just posting here, so it may help somebody.

After lots of struggle with trying all different solutions which not worked.

Only solution worked for me Uninstall all Android Studio setup. Like delete .gradle and .android and .AndroidStudio in Users -> pcusername folder.

Also deleted Android folder AppData -> Local -> Android folder.

and then do a Fresh install of Android studio setup worked for me.